# Cassandra DSC repair after very long time

Tags: cassandra, datastax, repair

I have a small cassandra DSC 2.2.8 cluster with 4 nodes that is for a long time now in service (more than 6 months). I have never run repair again and I am afraid that there may be deleted data resurrected. Is now too late for a repair? If I run `nodetool repair` the default is parallel mode, do I still need to run it in all 4 nodes one by one?

Comment: How much data are we talking about? How many Keyspaces and what is the replication factor?

Comment: 1 keyspace with replication factor 3 for about 8GB data.

Answer (score 0):

Nodetool Repair is a good way to optimize your node. Also improves the performance of the node. This will not resurrect the deleted data, in fact, will perform compaction(that will keep the latest record in database). You can perform repair on a DC as well as individual node.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, in case of a node down for over your gc_grace_period, other nodes may have remove tombstones and perform compaction, so if the broken node come back and you perform a repair, deleted data may be resurrected from the "previously broken" node because it will assume that this data is lost from other nodes

Comment: You should clear the SSTable if you think this can corrupt your data.